# Use MATCH with concatenation

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, match

I am using the following formula to match values from two columns:

```
=MATCH(C2,"000"&'Diversity Reports_12312013.xlsx'!snapshot[PERSONNEL_NUM],0)
```

but it is not working.

How might I match to another column but left pad three zeros to the value in that column?

Comment: why not just remove `000` from `C2` like this `=MATCH(Right(C2,Len(c2)-3),...`?

Comment: for some reason, it is not working either if I use right func... but if i copy and paste value only of the value after the right func, then it works... wondering if the format of cell threw it off?

Comment: try to add formula `=Right(C2,Len(c2)-3)` in any empty cell (say `D1`) and then use `=MATCH(D1,...)`. Does `D1` contains correct value ?

Comment: if it still doesn't work, try to evaluate *your initial formula* (`=MATCH(C2,"000"&'Diversity Reports_12312013.xlsx'!snapshot[PERSONNEL_NUM],0)`) by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (*not* just ENTER)

Comment: `RIGHT` function always returns a `text value` so assuming data is numeric try using either of these as lookup value - `RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-3)+0` or shorter `=REPLACE(C2,1,3,"")+0` - the +0 converts to a number

Comment: @barryhoudini, your `+0` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @simoco, I will try the suggested ways as well, thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0):

According to OP:

> @barryhoudini, your +0 did the trick, thanks!

@[barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini)'s 'trick' being:

```
 RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-3)+0
```

where "the +0 converts to a number".